# Bash script - how to keep looping 'find' command until file/s are found?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I am very new to linux scripting & am trying to set up a simple loop which will:

1. Ask user for file name
2. Search a specific directory for the file
3. If no files are found, ask the user to reinput a file name
4. If files are found, move on to the next step of the script

This is what I have so far, but it is not looping at all(i.e when no files are found, it is not asking the user to re-enter a file name. )

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter file name: " file
find /directory/ -name "$file" -print
while [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; do
       read -p "File not found. Please re-enter file name: " file
       find /directory/ -name "$file" -print
done
echo "rest of script etc"
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: `find` returns non-0 on error, not if there are no files found. See [this](http://serverfault.com/a/225827) for an easy fix. Also, consider adding `-quit` to your `find` commands to stop traversal after finding one match.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably using globstar (available with bash 4)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
while true; do
    read -p "Enter file name: " file
    for f in /directory/**/"$file"; do
        echo "$f"
        break 2 # escape both loops
    done
    echo "'$file' not found, please try again."
done
echo "rest of script etc"
```

It's also possible to do with `find`, but slightly annoying, given that you can't use standard UNIX exit statuses:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter file name: " file
found=$(find /directory/ -name "$file" -print -quit)
while [[ -z $found ]]; do
    read -p "File not found. Please re-enter file name: " file
    found=$(find /directory/ -name "$file" -print -quit)
done
echo "$found"
echo "rest of script etc"
```

Normally I wouldn't recommend parsing the output of `find`, but in this case we're only concerned as to whether or not there is any output.

Comment: You should explicitly enable globstar since it's not the default.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most portable way might be this:

```
# Loop until user inputted a valid file name
while true ; do
    # Read input (the POSIX compatible way)
    echo -n "Enter file name: "
    read file

    # Use find to check if the file exists
    [ $(find /etc -type f -name "$file" 2>/dev/null | wc -l ) != "0" ]  && break

    # go to next loop if the file does not exist
done

echo "Ok, go on here"
```

Comment: This does not do the same thing as what `find /directory -name "$file"` would do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion hek2mgl, but as @kojiro said this does not do the same thing.
I need to use the find command, and loop as long as the command is returning nothing.

Comment: A hint would have been enough, it was hard to get from the question. Especially when concentrating on the textual represention of the requirements. Thanks for the down-vote @kojiro. Good work!

Comment: @user3792362 Do you want to recursively search the directory? Meaning, also in it's sub directories?

Comment: @hek2mgl Yep I want to search every location under the /directory/